# Convert byte Encoding to unicode

Tags: r, unicode, encoding

I may not be using the appropriate language in the title.  If this needs edited please feel free.

I want to take a string with `"byte"` substitutions for unicode characters and convert them back to unicode.  Let's say I have:

```
x <- "bi<df>chen Z<fc>rcher hello world <c6>"
```

I'd like to get back:

```
"bißchen Zürcher hello world Æ"
```

I know that if I could get it to this form it would print to the console as desired:

```
"bi\xdfchen Z\xfcrcher \xc6"
```

I tried:

```
gsub("<([[a-z0-9]+)>", "\\x\\1", x)
## [1] "bixdfchen Zxfcrcher xc6"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
x <- "bi<df>chen Z<fc>rcher hello world <c6>"

m <- gregexpr("<[0-9a-f]{2}>", x)
codes <- regmatches(x, m)
chars <- lapply(codes, function(x) {
    rawToChar(as.raw(strtoi(paste0("0x", substr(x,2,3)))), multiple = TRUE)
})

regmatches(x, m) <- chars

x
# [1] "bi\xdfchen Z\xfcrcher hello world \xc6"

Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
x
# [1] "bißchen Zürcher hello world Æ"
```

Note that you can't make an escaped character by pasting a "\x" to the front of a number. That "\x" really isn't in the string at all. It's just how R chooses to represent it on screen. Here use use `rawToChar()` to turn a number into the character we want.

I tested this on a Mac so I had to set the encoding to "latin1" to see the correct symbols in the console. Just using a single byte like that isn't proper UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `gsubfn` library.

```
library(gsubfn)
f <- function(x) rawToChar(as.raw(as.integer(paste0("0x", x))), multiple=T)
gsubfn("<([0-9a-f]{2})>", f, "bi<df>chen Z<fc>rcher hello world <c6>")
## [1] "bißchen Zürcher hello world Æ"
```