# Problematic unicode encoding when using RJDBC

Tags: r, unicode

I am pulling data from a SQL table and putting it into a data frame using the RJDBC package in R. The data has Hebrew characters that are not displaying properly and I end up with strings like this:

`<U+05D4><U+05D0><U+05DD> <U+05D0><U+05EA><U+05D4>`

This only occurs when I am using a Windows machine using RJDBC in R. If I use Microsoft SQL Server or a Mac, I have no issues.

I can use the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248457/gsub-in-r-with-unicode-replacement-give-different-results-under-windows-compared?rq=1) to solve the problem, but I'd prefer something that allows me to read the data correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried playing with `options("encoding")`?

Comment: Yes. I can run `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` and it still has the same issues.

Comment: Have you tried encodings other than UTF-8? What is the encoding in the data base?

Comment: The database is UNICODE. I have tried "UCS-2LE", "UTF-8-BOM", and "UTF-16LE" but they don't fix the problem.